# Set BaseActivity with custom constructor to supply data from child class

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a `BaseActivity` I use in my app to help with make Google Analytics a bit easier.

In my base activity i override `onStart()` and `onStop()` to send some stuff to EasyTracker. I would like to set up my code so that it requires me to make a call through to the superclass constructor with the name of the activity so that the `BaseActivity` can send the right data along.

I tried setting up a constructor in the `BaseActivity`, and it seemed to work, but i got the error that my main activity (which extends `BaseActivity`) hierarchy is inconsistent.

What would I be able to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with constructors. The Android framework instantiates Android components (`Service`, `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`) itself and you can't muck around with that.

My suggestion is that you override `onCreate()` in your base activity and have your subclasses call `super.onCreate()` from their overridden `onCreate()` method. In your base activity you can get the name of the subclass by calling `getClass().getName()`.

Comment: Absolutely answered my question, thank you very much. Currently I'm doing something similar until I find a better method, but I need to send an actual string as the name as the class names don't suit my needs. Any auggestions ?

Comment: Sure. In the base class don't override `onCreate()`. Instead code your own method like `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String activityName)` which calls `super.onCreate()` and saves the `activityName`. Then, in the subclass, it should  override `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and in there, call `onCreate(savedInstanceState, activityName)`.

Comment: Again, works perfectly, thank you. Is there any way to make it so that i am required to call that method in any class that extends my `BaseActivity`?

Comment: Well, there isn't any way to force this at compile time. But what you can do is to have a private member variable in the base class that is initialized to `false`. Then, in `onCreate()` of your base class, you set this variable to `true` to indicate that the base class `onCreaate()` method has been called. Then, in the overridden `onStart()` of your base class, check if the variable has been set to `true`. If not, you can throw an exception saying "Subclass must call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, activityName)`"